# Volta Installation Problem: The term Volta is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

[image: At the powershell terminal]
C:\Users\91902\Documents\Source Websites\rocket.chat>volta pin node@14
at this if i am using volta command it is working but at the same directory if i am trying it on vsCode terminal then it is saying "The term 'volta' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program."

[image: terminal in the vsCode]

what should be the reason

I think it should work the same for the both terminal. I don't know what is causing this issue